# Kafka Node - client.createTopic fails code 38

Tags: node.js, docker, apache-kafka

i've created a small kafka code in node creating a topic.
i always get response with no error, but inside the data there is an error:

> received error code 38 for topic.

i'm using kafka docker to connect to kafka. image:

```
wurstmeister/zookeeper
```

here is the code:

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node')
consumerOptions = {groupId: 'auditGroup'}
const topic = 'Audit-test3'
const {
    Producer, Consumer, KeyedMessage, ConsumerGroup,
} = kafka
const kafkaHost = 'localhost:9092'
  console.log(`kafka - URL = ${kafkaHost}`)

  const clientTopic = {
    topic,
    partitions: 10,
    replicationFactor: 3
  }

  const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost })
  const producer = new Producer(client)
  const consumer = new Consumer(client, [], { autoCommit: true, ...consumerOptions })


  client.once('connect', () => {
    console.log('kafka - client connected')
    client.createTopics([clientTopic], clientTopicCallback)
    client.refreshMetadata([topic], () => console.log('kafka - client connected and refreshed metadata'))
  })

  const clientTopicCallback = (err, data) => {
    if(err){
      console.error(`kafka - error createing topic at client. ${err.message}. ${err.stack}`, err)
      return
    }

    if(data[0].error){
      console.error(`kafka - error createing topic at client. ${data[0].error}.`)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 38 is `INVALID_REPLICATION_FACTOR`. All Kafka error codes are documented in the protocol page: http://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes.

You are trying to create a topic with 3 replicas. The cluster typically returns this error if there are less online brokers than the requested replication factor.

Comment: this was probably the issue, once removed it passed

Answer (score 2):

Error code 38 means Replication-factor is invalid. How many kafka brokers do you have? If you want to set the replication-factor is 3, you need 3 available brokers at least.